# Defining my sympleTypes gives "Type is not declared, or is not a simple type"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have defined two sympleTypes (CommonTypes.xsd) that I would like to use in several other XSD files (e.g. MotorList.xsd).

I use the Visual Studio to develop. The Visual Studio does not complain about any troubles. Both files do have the 'Build Action' set to 'Embedded Resource'. But when I run my application which validates the XSD files then I get 'Type http://Ford/Mustang/PowerPlugin/CommonTypes:powerType' is not declared, or is not a simple type'.

What is wrong?

Thanks for any help.

File CommonTypes.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://Ford/Mustang/PowerPlugin/CommonTypes">

  <xs:simpleType name="powerType" >
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="unitType" final="restriction" >
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="kW" />
      <xs:enumeration value="PS" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Nm" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

File MotorList.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://MyNamespace/MyTypes" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:commonTypes="http://Ford/Mustang/PowerPlugin/CommonTypes">

  <xs:import namespace="http://Ford/Mustang/PowerPlugin/CommonTypes"
             schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="MotorList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Prime">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="cylinder" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="power" type="commonTypes:powerType" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="unit" type="commonTypes:unitType" use="optional" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema documents are fine (I tested them with Saxon). The problem is therefore something to do with the way you are using them (which you've told us very little about). One possibility is that the schema processor didn't actually find the CommonTypes.xsd document - a good way to check that would be to introduce a deliberate error and see if it gets reported. Then tell us how you are invoking the validation that fails (and what schema processor you are using).

Comment: Thanks Michael. It's good to know that xsd files are correct. I will then check as next the schmema loading.